# Is there a way to show / hide a <div> depending on the size of the browser?

Tags: css, angularjs, media-queries

Angular JS code I am working on has media queries that can be used to limit the display of  blocks with code like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 370px) {
    #testGrid {
        .gridHeader {
            div:nth-child(2),
            div:nth-child(3),
            div:nth-child(n+7) {
                display: none;
            }

            div:nth-child(6) {
                border-top-right-radius: 0.4rem;
            }
        }

        .gridBody {
            div {
                div:nth-child(2),
                div:nth-child(3),
                div:nth-child(n+7) {
                    display: none;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My comment here was that it's not good to use things like `div:nth-child(2)` as this would easily break if another column was added. Plus it's also difficult to maintain. I suggested to give the column names class names that matched the contents of the columns.

Still this means that I have the code that defines what shows and what does not show far removed from the HTML. Does anyone have any suggestions on a way that I could do this with AngularJS that would have the showing and hiding of columns next to the actual  `<div>`s

Comment: You could give Foundation a try: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html

Comment: Thanks but our code is already in AngularJS and it cannot be changed at this point.  Just looking for some possible options as I know it's good to keep things together and I find it hard to maintain the app when showing / hiding of columns is in a file that's not the actual html file.

Comment: You can also give 1 same class to all the div's i.e. hide_small_screen. Also, what you mean by actual div's?

Comment: @nikhil - That's a very good suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current width from the `$window` service so you could try something like this:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iDruY9YCLOUmt3AQDpZI?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

  $scope.name = 'World';

   angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
        $scope.hideThing = ($window.innerWidth < 400);

        // have to manually update $scope as angular won't know about the resize event
        $scope.$digest();
    });

});
```

Then in your HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-hide="hideThing" >Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```